# Emacs - switch to buffer by typing extension and then file name

Tags: emacs

is it possible in emacs to search filename in a way that i type in the extension first then space and after that file name itself? E.g. *org notes* org *or not* will switch to notes.org.

Or is there any way to write such a function to do exactly that?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the use case for this kind of feature?

Comment: It would let me see easily all files of given type in case way to many buffers are opened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use ido you can type org c-space notes.

Ido takes a little while to get used to, but personally I cant live without it.

Comment: For those of you about to upvote ido, checkout anything-config.  The split window lets you see long strings such as file/buffer names much better, and there is a ton of predefined sources you can mix and match.

Comment: Personally i use ido, and yep, it can do it. Something like this ``C-x b .extension M-m name``. @event_jr I've never used "icicles" or "anything" before(but I used iswitchb and commented it out since ido can do better). Can you say in a few words about Ido/Icicles/Anything compatibility? Are they all making the same things, or there is a reason to use them together?

Comment: AFAIK anything is compatible with ido.  I don't see a reason to use both though.  Ido and anything do similar things, except anything shows the choices in a regular buffer, not the minibuffer.

Answer (score 3):

[Anything](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) can do this easily, run anything, type any words in the buffer's name, results shows:

[image: Emacs Anything]

follow this to install it: http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/09/finding-just-about-anything.html

if you can want to filter buffer, here is a example config for you:

```
(require 'anything-config)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b")
            (lambda() (interactive)
              (anything
               :prompt "Switch to: "
               :sources
               '(anything-c-source-buffers))))
```

Comment: Pity no bigger version of the image is opened if I click on it. Would be useful to actually read what's on the screenshot to get a grasp of this feature.

Comment: The default anything-config matcher does exactly what the OP requested.  If the first word is also a major-mode, i.e. org, then anything uses the major-mode as a filter.

Comment: Tom: Just open the image directly -- it's actually bigger than that (not to mention entertainingly recursive).

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with Anders, [IDO](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) is quite useful. For example, if you have two buffers "some-video-page.js" and "video.py" you can enter "C-x b vidjs" or "C-x b vidpy" to switch to either of those.

```
(ido-mode)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

Also consider using [ibuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) to organize you buffers. You can filter buffers by full file name and close multiple buffers based on your current filter.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

Returning to your question. There is [uniquify](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/uniquify) library that is now shipped with Emacs and it will include name of the parent directory in buffer names by default. But this is emacs we are speaking about and you can customize it however you want. I have a custom file-hook that prefixes only python buffers with python module name. Will IDO be enough for you or do you still want your custom switch-buffers function?

Answer (score 1):

[***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) does this out of the box -- just use <kbd>S-TAB</kbd> instead of <kbd>TAB</kbd> for completion -- i.e., [apropos completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#PrefixAndAproposCompletion) rather than prefix completion.

To complete against multiple patterns (e.g. substrings) without regard to their order, use [progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ProgressiveCompletion).  You use <kbd>S-SPC</kbd> to separate the patterns.

```
    C-x C-f notes S-SPC org
```

or

```
    C-x C-f org S-SPC notes
```

or, to be sure that `org` is matched as a file extension, use `\.org`.  (Or use <kbd>C-`</kbd> to toggle substring/regexp matching, i.e., escaping of regexp special chars.)

Same thing if you use buffer-name completion  (or any other kind of completion) rather than file-name completion.

As for Ido's "flex" matching, *Icicles* has the same thing (it's called "scatter" matching), as well as several other types of [fuzzy matching](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion).  (But all forms of fuzzy matching are less useful than they sound, IMHO.)

Answer (score 1):

You can (approximately) do this by default by using name globbing.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> `*.org` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Emacs moves point automatically to sit after the asterisk, so you can immediately continue typing part of the buffer name.

Also `*org` is slightly easier to type than `*.org` and would probably get you sufficiently similar results for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

[Iswitchb](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Iswitchb.html#Iswitchb), shipped with Emacs, doesn't do exactly this, but close. It shows a list of buffer names in the minibuffer. As you type, the list narrows down to the buffers whose name contain the text you've typed (anywhere, not just at the beginning). So if you type `.org`, then you'll be down to the buffers whose name contains `.org`. To open a specific file amongst these, you would then need to either move the cursor to the left and type the last letters of the file name, or press `C-r` or `C-s` to rotate amongst the matches.

The Emacs wiki has a [page on Iswitchb](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers) and a [comparison of Icicles, Ido and Iswitchb](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Ido_and_IswitchB).

Comment: I love iswitchb, but I never knew about the C-r/C-s thing, which is incredibly helpful. :)